# Parameterised T4 Template via Add New Item

Tags: t4

I am just starting to cut my teeth on T4 Templates and my first experiment is trying to add some T4 Templates to use from VS via Add New Item.

In my case I am initially looking at creating SQL templates, but this is not SQL specific, however you can imagine that I have a general template for a Stored Procedure and there are (at least) 4 distinct flavours/variations of the template (e.g. should it use a Transaction or not).

I could create 4 separate templates and have the user select which variant they want from the Add New Item dialog, but it feels like I ought to be able to somehow define some parameters to use in creating the 4 variants of output from the one template.

Only the User selecting the Add New Item would know what they were after - so ideally I would like to get input from the user (imagine a check box for Transactional?).

Is this possible? I want to avoid creating multiple templates if possible - but if I need to I can at least look to inherit the base structure to minimise code duplication.

Thanks

Stuart